# Android ICS bug: programmatically showing a screen which contains a ListView, results in list becoming unfocusable

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

We have 2 screens: 
The first screen contains a button for displaying the next screen and a `ListView`. The `ListView` items are focusable at first. But when returning from the second screen to the first one ( calling `setContentView( )` ), it seems that the list cannot be focused anymore.

I'm pretty sure this an Android 4.0 bug, just checking if anyone else has encountered it.
Here's the code snippet:

```
public class ListTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        createFirstScreen();
        createSecondScreen();

        setContentView(mFirstScreen);
    }
    public void createFirstScreen()
    {
        mFirstScreen = new LinearLayout(this);
        mNextBtn = new Button(this);
        mNextBtn.setText("Next");
        mNextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                setContentView(mSecondScreen);
            }
        });

        mListView = new ListView(this);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                  "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                  "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mFirstScreen.addView(mNextBtn);
        mFirstScreen.addView(mListView);
    }

    public void createSecondScreen()
    {
        mSecondScreen = new LinearLayout(this);
        mBackBtn = new Button(this);
        mBackBtn.setText("Back");
        mBackBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(mFirstScreen);
            }
        });
        mSecondScreen.addView(mBackBtn);
    }

    private LinearLayout mFirstScreen;
    private ListView mListView;
    private Button mNextBtn;
    private Button mBackBtn;
    private LinearLayout mSecondScreen;
}
```